How to traverse mapping?
I have a solidity mapping like:
mapping(bytes32 => SomeStruct) myMap;

whose size dynamically increases.
Can I traverse myMap at first with keys and also without keys just with indexes, like we do in case of array?

In order to traverse your mapping i.e., mapping(bytes32 => SomeStruct) myMap, you can store the keys of type bytes32 in a bytes32 array, during the assignment of mapping keys and values. Like:
bytes32[] public keys;

function setMapping(bytes32 _key, uint _value) public {
    // Add the key to the array if it doesn't already exist
    if (myMap[_key].value == 0) {
        keys.push(_key);
    }

    // Update the mapping
    myMap[_key] = SomeStruct(_value);
}

Then, you can traverse the same by traversing through the elements of keys array, like:
function traverseMapping() public view returns (SomeStruct[] memory) {
    SomeStruct[] memory values = new SomeStruct[](keys.length);

    for (uint i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        values[i] = myMap[keys[i]];
    }

    return values;
}

Here’s the minimal example for the same:
contract MyContract {
    struct SomeStruct {
        uint value;
        // other fields can be added here
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => SomeStruct) public myMap;
    bytes32[] public keys;

    function setMapping(bytes32 _key, uint _value) public {
        // Add the key to the array if it doesn't already exist
        if (myMap[_key].value == 0) {
            keys.push(_key);
        }

        // Update the mapping
        myMap[_key] = SomeStruct(_value);
    }

    function getKeys() public view returns (bytes32[] memory) {
        return keys;
    }

    function traverseMapping() public view returns (SomeStruct[] memory) {
        SomeStruct[] memory values = new SomeStruct[](keys.length);

        for (uint i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            values[i] = myMap[keys[i]];
        }

        return values;
    }
}


will it be possible to create bytes32[] public keys;   as keys will dynamically increase ?

bytes32[] public keys; is a dynamic bytes32 array, where you can store keys whenever a new key-value pair is added to your mapping.

thanks a lot....

You’re welcome, @NersesAsaturyan. Happy coding!
